# using the DIAMOND operator with xml::twig

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I have the following xml::twig

```
my $t = XML::Twig->new(
twig_handlers => {

 r => sub {   #my code here}            

 );
$t->parse( <>); #I want here to read multiple files as input and parse them but get an error ,
```

is it possible to do that with xml::twig ?

Comment: Please post your actual code (there's a missing `}` somewhere in there), and the error message you are getting.

Comment: Six questions but none of them marked as accepted.  Why is that? Please go back and mark your old questions’ answers as accepted so that people will want to bother with helping you.

Answer (score 2):

The `XML::Twig::parse` method takes a single scalar argument, not a list, so `parse(<>)` is the wrong approach.

But what about

```
$t->parse(  join "", <>  )
```

?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is possible.  From `perldoc perlvar`:

ARGV

The special filehandle that iterates over command-line filenames in @ARGV. Usually written as the null filehandle in the angle operator "<>". Note that currently "ARGV" only has its magical effect within the "<>" operator; elsewhere it is just a plain filehandle corresponding to the last file opened by "<>". In particular, passing "*ARGV" as a parameter to a function that expects a filehandle may not cause your function to automatically read the contents of all the files in @ARGV.